# How to send latency metrics from Apache Storm to a Graphite server?

Tags: apache-storm, graphite

I have configured Apache Storm to send metrics to Graphite server using the [version 2](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.2/metrics_v2.html). It is sending a `count` parameter of all my bolts and spouts. I would like to send the latency between the communication of the bolts and spouts, and the time to process each tuple on them as well. However, everything that I find on the Graphite server is metrics related to `count` tuples on bolts and spouts. The documentation says it is possible to collect Histograms, Timers, etc. But does not explain how it is possible to collect it.

```
# Metrics v2 configuration (optional)
storm.metrics.reporters:
  # Graphite Reporter
  - class: "org.apache.storm.metrics2.reporters.GraphiteStormReporter"
    daemons:
        - "supervisor"
        - "nimbus"
        - "worker"
    report.period: 30
    report.period.units: "SECONDS"
    graphite.host: "127.0.0.1"
    graphite.port: 2003
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included a `Meter` on all Bolts and now it is showing on the Graphite web server.

```
public class MqttSensorDetailSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
    ...
    private Meter tupleMeter;
    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        this.tupleMeter = context.registerMeter("meterSpout-" + this.topic);
    }
    public void nextTuple() {
        this.tupleMeter.mark();
        ...
    }
}
```

[image]